# setup Grails project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I have the following directory structure

```
--my-app
   |
   |--main-app
   |
   |--plugins
      |
      |--plugin1
      |
      |--plugin2
```

In grails-app/conf/BuildConfig I've added the necessary configuration to ensure that the plugins are loaded from the `plugins` directory, so that when I run the application, it picks up the most recent changes.

I'm trying to set this up as a single project in IntelliJ which has 3 modules, one for the main application and one for each of the two plugins. I tried the following:

- Generate the IntelliJ project files

  `cd my-app/main-app`

  `grails integrate-with --intellij`
- Open the generated .ipr file from inside Intellij (File | Open Project...). This adds the main application and plugins as Grails modules

However every time I open a class from a plugin, IntelliJ reports that the class has two occurrences. It seems each plugin class is being detected

1. once in the IntelliJ module for the plugin itself
2. once in the module that IntelliJ automatically creates which contains all the plugins. In my case, this module is named `main-app-grailsPlugins`

In the project structure view I tried removing the content roots for `plugin1` and `plugins2` from `main-app-grailsPlugins`, but they get automatically added back again.

Is there a way to prevent this, or some other way of correctly setting up an IntelliJ project for a Grails app with in-place plugins. I'm using Grails 1.3.7 and IntelliJ 10.5.4

Comment: Have you tried to import your Grails project from existing source in IDEA, without using integrate-with? Which class is reported as duplicated, where is it located?

Comment: The duplicate problem does not occur if I don't use integrate-with, but the dependencies between the main app and the plugin aren't setup correctly if I do it this way

Comment: Don, try to execute Synchronize Grails Settings on 'main-app' module.

Comment: The import feature sucks in regards to inPlace-plugins! See below for a step-by-step guide to setting up inplace plugins and main apps in intelliJ :)

Answer (score 1):

With ***IntelliJ IDEA 12 Ultimate*** this is very easy:

```
"File" 
    --> "Import Project..." 
         --> select your grails application, "OK" 
             --> Select "Create project from existing sources", "Next" 
                --> "Next" 
                    --> "Next" 
                        --> Select JDK, "Next" 
                             --> Select grails version, "Next" 
                                  --> "Finish"
```

The inplace plugins will automatically be added as modules.
Result: http://d.pr/i/YHkk

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked beautifully for me in a similar situation:

1. Make sure that your local plugins are referenced correctly:

   `grails.plugin.location.MyPlugin= "../plugins/MyPlugin"`
2. Start out by creating an empty project - that is, no modules!
3. Do not import or in any other way "autogenerate" ipr files
4. Important! Start out with the lower plugins in your "dependency graph"
5. Click file->New Module
6. Choose grails module
7. Point "content root" to the root of your plugin (Module name should be filled in automatically)
8. Repeat 5-7 until no more plugins
9. Finish by creating a module for your main app in similar manner as 5-7

This does it for me with many more plugins than two!